# Ressources duplicated when exporting war file from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, configuration, war

I have an application in Eclipse which I want to export in a war file. For that, I simply do `File > Export > War file`.
It works fine, and the deployed application runs correctly.

But in the war file, I have the properties file which are duplicated in two folders :
`WEB-INF\classes` and `WEB-INF\conf`

What setting can I change to avoid that ?

They are currently under the folder `MyApp\WebContent\WEB-INF\conf\bdd.properties`

Also, is it possible to have two properties files : one for the development platform, one for the production platform, and to choose which one I want to export ?

Thanks for your help